# Understanding Compiler Optimizations

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

I'm trying to understand what the compiler is doing to very simple piece of code:

```
if (group.ImageHeight > 1 && group.ImageWidth > 1)
{ //No code exists between the braces
}
```

After compiling in `Debug` configuration, then decompiling I see this:

```
if (group.ImageHeight <= 1 || group.ImageWidth <= 1);
```

Decompiling a `Release` configuration results in

```
if (group.ImageHeight > 1)
{
  int imageWidth = group.ImageWidth;
}
```

More complete (original) code:

```
public class Group 
{
  public int ImageHeight { get; set; }
  public int ImageWidth { get; set; }
}

//The following belongs to a different project than `Group`
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Group group = new Group();
  MyMethod(group);
}
static void MyMethod(Group group)
{
    if (group.ImageHeight > 1 && group.ImageWidth > 1)
    { 
    }
}
```

Here are my guesses and observations so far:

- When I first started this I expected the compiler to completely drop the entire statement.  I think that it's not because the evaluation of the properties could have side effects.
- I believe that it's important that `group` type belongs to another project in my solution.  I say this because the compiler probably can't "know" what the side effects of evaluating the properties could be in the future.  For instance, I could, after compiling, replace the DLL that contains the definition for `group`.
- In the `Release` config the possible side effects appear to be the same as my code: `ImageHeight` is evaluated and if meets the `> 1` condition will evaluate `ImageWidth` (although through assignment rather than comparison)

Now, for my specific questions:

- Why does the `Release` config use an assignment (`int imageWidth = group.ImageWidth`) rather than my original comparison?  Is it faster to run an assignment?
- Why does the `Debug` configuration completely change the possibility of side effects?  In this configuration both `ImageHeight` and `ImageWidth` will always be evaluated.

Comment: Since group is declared in Main() and is logically on the heap and since MyMethod is static and is passed in the "global" Main variable group...  Your are giving the optimizer a free pass to make some big assumptions.   If the variables and code blocks went in and out of scope you might see results closer to what you would expect.  Also you have no code in your int property accessors, another free pass. That's my 2 bits.

Comment: Bear in mind that the C# compiler itself doesn't tend to do lots of "strong" optimizations. A lot of the stronger optimizations are left to the JIT compiler instead. Also, you have to consider that whatever decompiler you're using has as much influence over what you see "after" as the C# compiler. If you want to know what the C# compiler is doing, you ought to be looking at the IL level, not at what some other tools re-interprets the IL as.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, that makes sense and something I'll keep in mind.  IL level is a bit above my head...maybe I should learn one of these days :)

Comment: Yeah, IL is one of those things that is remarkably "simple" or remarkably "complex". It depends to a good extent on whether you "get" [Stack Machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first specific question. When you look at IL on [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgBgATIIwG4CwAUOsZgMyYBM6A4gE4D2ArgA7qEDehxy5YAdsHQBJALYBDAOYBTABJSwEgBaD26acBzoAzlI3oAvlzLp+g0ZKkB1MDGCL0q9Zp17DBNz0roAwg8L+CAHpAgBVFKXQAM3oICHoAd34JdAAjKTi+CS10YHp0MXQYMEjIqVopAXRmBgArKQBjQTsxPnQAAzomZjbCbAA2TAAWdABZMX4ACmxUAG0AXXzaLIBKDiNOljUGTYBedD4peJpt5gnl/CJRgE8R3UV6GAmJE/PCDywB5GGRm7uHiY2rGeXVWBE4l2IxXQTxOADpzNI5AplOgAHzoLDoABkWK2XXh4mk1ls9nRWFBJAcbAhBjebyAA===)
The simple assignment is 1 compare instruction short. Whose "then" and "else" would point to the same instruction (in this case IL_0012) so compare there is not needed for calling function and two pops are enough. Weird is only loading the Int32 constant 1 which will be discarded immidiately.

if (group.ImageHeight > 1)

```
IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: callvirt instance int32 Group::get_ImageHeight()
IL_0006: ldc.i4.1
IL_0007: ble.s IL_0012
```

int imageWidth = group.ImageWidth;

```
IL_0009: ldarg.0
IL_000a: callvirt instance int32 Group::get_ImageWidth()
IL_000f: ldc.i4.1
IL_0010: pop
IL_0011: pop

IL_0012: ret
```

For second specific question. If you look at IL on the same page with Debug mode, you'll see, that the code is identical only with some additional instructions for debuging and the compare itself so you can watch the result of it in debuger.

```
IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldarg.0
IL_0002: callvirt instance int32 Group::get_ImageHeight()
IL_0007: ldc.i4.1
IL_0008: ble.s IL_0015

IL_000a: ldarg.0
IL_000b: callvirt instance int32 Group::get_ImageWidth()
IL_0010: ldc.i4.1
IL_0011: cgt
IL_0013: br.s IL_0016

IL_0015: ldc.i4.0

IL_0016: stloc.0
        // sequence point: hidden
IL_0017: ldloc.0
IL_0018: brfalse.s IL_001c

IL_001a: nop
IL_001b: nop

IL_001c: ret
```

Comment: "so you can watch the result of it in debuger".  That line right there is very helpful.  I was struggling to see why the result would be different between debug/release.